# How to show data asynchronously from URL that return document.write()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are using a 3rd Party application that provides Javascript code that returns the data using `document.write()` method. i.e.,

`<script src="//demoUrl.com/response/" type="text/javascript"></script>`

The data shown on this URL is like this:

`document.write('This is the output');`

So, this process works fine when we use this script as it is, but when we add `async` or defer attribute on this script tag, the output does not show.

How we can show the data asynchronously so it did not stop the page load?

Answer (score 1):

Persuade the third party to rewrite the script so it doesn't use `document.write` as it is entirely incompatible with delayed execution.

See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Compatibility_notes):

> Never call document.write() from an async script. In Firefox 3.6, calling document.write() has an unpredictable effect. In Firefox 4, calling document.write() from an async script has no effect (other than printing a warning to the error console).

Comment: That 3rd party is one of the leading email marketing company. Not sure, if they can change their script in the quick manner. So, we have to find a solution that work for us in the mean time. :) Thanks for the information.